# How to do Chi-square test correctly using chisq.test()?

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform Pearson Chi-square test on goodness of fit. Here is an example of fitting a Poisson distribution:

```
data <- rpois(200,50)
estimate <- mean(data)
freq.os<-table(data)
yfit <- dpois(as.integer(names(freq.os)), estimate)

chisq.test(x = freq.os, p = yfit)
# Error in chisq.test(x = freq.os, p = yfit) : probabilities must sum to 1.
```

When I evaluate `sum(yfit)`, I get 0.999839.

So how to produce a set of probability values that add up to 1? Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

Actually I found a work around:

```
chisq.test(freq.os, yfit)
```

but I am very confused as to how `chisq.test()` works as it is telling me `df = 429`. I thought `df = n - k - 1`, which in this case should be 35, where `k = 1` for the lambda and `n = number` of terms in the chi-square sum. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments above suggested you to manually rescale `yfit`, before passing it to `chisq.test`. Well actually you can let `chisq.test()` do this for you:

```
chisq.test(x = freq.os, p = yfit, rescale.p = TRUE)
```

---

**Regarding your Edit**

```
chisq.test(freq.os, yfit)
```

is incorrect, as it is doing independence test.

`chisq.test()` can perform two statistical test:

1. goodness of fit test, using argument `x` and `p`;
2. independence test, using argument `x` and `y`.

Please read `?chisq.test` carefully. For goodness of fit test, you must use `p` argument in the function, as you initially did. My answer above, using `rescale.p = TRUE` will help you get around the error you saw.

---

**How to do Pearson Chi-square test**

You said you don't know how the test is done, then read this part.

You should use `set.seed()`, so that when others run your code, they get the same random numbers as you got. Here is a reproducible example:

```
N <- 200    ## number of samples
set.seed(0)    ## fix random seed for reproducibility
x <- rpois(N,50)    ## generate sample
lambda <- mean(x)    ## estimate mean
```

Now we aim to use Pearson Chi-square test to test goodness of fit. We have

> Null Hypothesis: x ~ Poisson(lambda)

```
O <- table(x)    ## contingency table / observed frequency
n <- length(O)    ## number of categories
# 31
x0 <- as.integer(names(O))    ## unique sample values
p <- dpois(x0, lambda); p <- p / sum(p)    ## theoretical probability under Null Hypothesis
```

**Let's first perform Chi-square test ourselves.**

```
E <- p * N    ## expected frequency under Null Hypothesis
R <- (O - E) / sqrt(E)    ## standardised residuals
X <- sum(R * R)    ## Chi-square statistic
# 36.13962
dof <- n - 1    ## degree of freedom
# 30
p.value <- 1 - pchisq(X, df = dof)    ## p-value
# 0.2035416
```

The p-value is larger than 0.05, hence we can not reject Null Hypothesis. Summary plot:

```
z <- curve(dchisq(x, df = dof), from = 0, to = 100)
abline(v = X, lty = 3)
polygon(c(X, X, z$x[z$x > X]), c(0, dchisq(X, df = dof), z$y[z$x > X]), col = 2)
```

[image]

**Then we use `chisq.test()`**

```
chisq.test(O, p = p)

#Chi-squared test for given probabilities

#data:  O
#X-squared = 36.14, df = 30, p-value = 0.2035
```

You can see, the result is the same.